# How to avoid "Permission denied" when using pip with virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I attempt to deploy a Python package with `pip` in a virtual environment on an Ubuntu machine, but encounter a permission-related issue. For example:

```
(TestVirtualEnv)test@testServer:~$ pip install markdown2
```

terminates by:

> error: could not create '/home/test/virtualenvs/TestVirtualEnv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/markdown2.py': Permission denied

I can't `sudo`, since it will install the package globally, and not within the virtual environment. I `chown`ed `site-packages`; `ls` shows only directories related to `easy_install`, `pip` and `setuptools`, and nothing related to Markdown.

How to deploy a package in a virtual environment with `pip` without encountering permission-related errors?

Comment: Just to clarify: did you create this virtualenv with `sudo`?

Comment: @sebastian_oe: I *believe* I did. I'll recreate one to be sure.

Comment: Then this might be the problem. Try creating a virtualenv without `sudo`.

Comment: @sebastian_oe: I created a virtual environment without `sudo`. Indeed, the package installs correctly now. Please, can you promote your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Also if you are switching between different users, make sure you are using user that owns (or has write access) `virtualenv` directory, because you can activate `virtualenv` with other user, but it won't let you install any packages and will give permission access.

Comment: Another possible cause is creating the virtualenv from linux on an NTFS partition. Try recreating it on e.g. an ext3 or ext4 partition.

Comment: one option, change permissions for the virtual environment to all users, see https://superuser.com/a/630093/1235905

Answer (score 119, accepted):

`virtualenv` permission problems might occur when you create the `virtualenv` as `sudo` and then operate without `sudo` in the `virtualenv`.

As found out in your question's comment, the solution here is to **create** the `virtualenv` without `sudo` to be able to **work** (esp. write) in it without `sudo`.

Comment: if I want to create it in /opt which requires sudo, I think virtualenv won't install without sudo.

Comment: How to create the `virtualenv` without sudo?

Comment: If you did create the virtualenv with `sudo`, see answer by @vingtoft for how to fix it easily without recreating

Answer (score 142):

**Solution:**

If you created the virtualenv as root, run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R your_username:your_username path/to/virtuaelenv/
```

This will probably fix your problem.

Cheers

Comment: This worked for me (chown /usr/local/lib/python3.4), except I don't think I had created a virtualenv as root, I had actually installed Python3.4 as root. I'm still testing, but do you think I will run into any more issues with this solution, or will this chown fix most errors?

Comment: How do you find out if you've created virtualenv or python as root?

Comment: This fixed my problem. I was in a similar situation as the OP in that I needed to create a virtual environment in /opt/ directory which I couldn't do without sudo privileges.

Comment: This works. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you created virtual environment using root then use this command

```
sudo su
```

it will give you the root access and then activate your virtual environment using this

```
source /root/.env/ENV_NAME/bin/activate
```

Comment: this helped me with my permission denied errors when installing dependencies from requirements.txt (django) 
It seems that the venv has to be activated from root.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was using `mkvirtualenv`, but didn't tell it I was going to be using python3.  I got this error:

```
mkvirtualenv hug
pip3 install hug -U

....
error: could not create '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages': Permission denied
```

It worked after specifying python3:

```
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 hug
pip3 install hug -U
```

Answer (score 6):

I was getting `permission denied` when trying to activate my virtual environment. I landed on this page trying to find solutions so perhaps this could also help others who are facing similar issues

```
source your_env_name_goes_here/bin/activate
```

I was using the wrong command (without the `source`), to activate my environment. If you're on `zsh` that's the correct command to use. If not, [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) has a table of the commands to use depending on your platform and shell (windows or mac, bash or powershell etc)

Answer (score 5):

I didn't create my virtualenv using sudo. So Sebastian's answer didn't apply to me. My project is called `utils`. I checked `utils` directory and saw this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 macuser  staff   983  6 Jan 15:17 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   6 root     staff   204  6 Jan 14:36 utils.egg-info
-rw-r--r--   1 macuser  staff    31  6 Jan 15:09 requirements.txt
```

As you can see, `utils.egg-info` is owned by `root` not `macuser`. That is why it was giving me `permission denied` error. I also had to remove `/Users/macuser/.virtualenvs/armoury/lib/python2.7/site-packages/utils.egg-link` as it was created by `root` as well. I did `pip install -e .` again after removing those, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You **did not activate the virtual environment** before using pip.

Try it with:

```
$(your venv path) . bin/activate
```

And then use pip -r requirements.txt on your main folder

Answer (score 1):

I've also had this happen (by accident) after creating a new venv while inside an existing virtual environment.  an easy way to diagnose this would be to see where the `python` is symlinked to, i.e. run:

```sh
ls -l venv/bin/python
```

and make sure it points to the appropriate Python binary.  For most systems this will be `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python3`.  while if it points to an existing virtual environment it'll be something like `/home/youruser/somedir/bin/python`.  if it's the latter than I'd suggest recreating the venv while making sure that you aren't "inside" any existing virtualenv (i.e. run `deactivate` )

Comment: posted here because it's a popular question that mentions the appropriate keywords, hence is more likely to be found and be useful to other people

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I created *and activated a venv as a regular user in Git Bash within VS Code running on Windows 11 and got a "permission denied" when trying to run pip. I could not use sudo at all (corporate laptop).

My solution was:

Create your venv like normal (non-root user):

```
python -m venv <venv_name>
```

Activate your venv:

```
source venv/Scripts/activate
```

Then, assuming you're using a requirements.txt file, run:

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The key is the "python -m"

You may need to upgrade your pip if a package fails to install properly. Try:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

then try reinstalling your requirements.

---

If you want to confirm this is the same error to the solution above, you can recreate the error by:

*after you activate your venv, run:

```
python --version
```

or

```
which python
```

and they should both indicate you're using the python within your venv (again, assuming you activated it)

Then run:

```
pip --version
```

and you should see your permission denied.

```
$ pip --version

bash: \venv/Scripts/pip: Permission denied
```

Then running

```
python -m pip --version
```

should show you the correct pip version of the venv and path within your venv.

Answer (score 0):

While creating virtualenv if you use sudo the directory is created with root privileges.So when you try to install a package with non-sudo user you won't have permission to install into it.
So always create virtualenv without sudo and install without sudo.

You can also copy packages installed on global python to virtualenv.

```
cp -r /lib/python/site-packages/* virtualenv/lib/python/site-packages/
```

Comment: This was not the problem: if you read the comments, the OP had created the virtual env with sudo in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

On centos 7 this worked:

first, create it

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.8 fastapi
```

then to activate

```
source fastapi/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue also.  I've checked my file & directory ownership and permissions using `ls -hal`.  I own the files and they have the right permissions.  For me, the issue is running the `pip` command, but it's the wrong `pip`. Try running `which pip` to find out which version of pip is being used.  From the activated virtual environment, run `python3 -m pip install packagename` instead of `pip install packagename`.  If it gets worse, you can run `/path/to/the/pip/you/want/pip install filename`.