# 'Permission denied' error when using pip install in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Edit: FIXED!

Just had to chown the .cache directory

I've tried the [virtualenvwrapper docs](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instructions, I've tried [this guy's instructions](http://roundhere.net/journal/virtualenv-ubuntu-12-10/) as well as [these](http://chrisstrelioff.ws/sandbox/2014/09/04/virtualenv_and_virtualenvwrapper_on_ubuntu_14_04.html)...I've tried `sudo pip uninstall virtualenv`
, `sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper`, `sudo pip3 uninstall virtualenv`, `sudo pip3 uninstall virtualenvwrapper` before attempting each set of instructions. I've looked at other SO posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471972/how-to-avoid-permission-denied-when-using-pip-with-virtualenv), but the sudo issue isn't the same as my own. By this, I mean that I don't use sudo when making the virtualenv, and if I try to use sudo to pip install a package, it'll just say that I've already installed the package (outside of the virtualenv).

I've also tried doing `pip install --user virtualenv(wrapper)`

Here's what I did:

```
~ $ sudo pip3 install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-13.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.7MB): 1.7MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv
Cleaning up...
~ $ mkdir ~/.virtualenvs
~ $ sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
Downloading/unpacking virtualenvwrapper
  Downloading virtualenvwrapper-4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Installing collected packages: virtualenvwrapper
Successfully installed virtualenvwrapper
Cleaning up...
~ $ export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs/
```

Then I added these two lines to my .bashrc: (I also tried setting `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to `/usr/bin/python`)

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3'
```

Next I tried this:

```
~ $ mkvirtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
(test)~ $ pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aweeeezy/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/aweeeezy/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 291, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/aweeeezy/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 754, in build
    ensure_dir(output_dir)
  File "/home/aweeeezy/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 70, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/home/aweeeezy/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/home/aweeeezy/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/home/aweeeezy/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/home/aweeeezy/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/aweeeezy/.cache/pip/wheels/4b'
```

Why can't virtualenv just work?

Comment: Looks like one of the directories is funky. Won't let you in...

Comment: Make sure to source the venv before, so you don't have any dependencies to your original environment.

Comment: @JosephSeungJaeDollar, like `source ~/.virtualenvs/test`? This won't work because the venv is a directory.

edit: you mean, `source ~/virtualenvs/test/bin/activate`, right? Thpat still doesn't help.

Comment: In what way did you chown the .cache directory? who did you set the new owner to? Did you change the permissions?

Comment: This was fixed in pip version 7.1.1 (2015-08-20) http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/news/

Comment: add Edit: at the end of the question. Answers were useful at the time of the question.

Comment: @aweeeezy add your EDIT as an answer, so people will see it

Answer (score 16):

I think that if you do that `pip install numpy --no-cache-dir` it will work.

If you run `pip --help` you will find:

`--no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.`

Hope that it can help to someone in the future.

Comment: This 100% helped me today in case someone comes across the same issue. One other thing though is I removed the virtual environment completely and started over using this command in addition to --user. Thanks, Vladir!

Comment: Good that it helped @TravisVOX.

Answer (score 8):

you need to change the owner of directory of pip.

run `chown -R <user>:<group> /home/aweeeezy/.cache/pip`.

Comment: For newbies, chown -R $USER /home/aweeeezy/.cache/pip will also work.