# Can't install on Mac using pip or easy_install in terminal

Tags: python, django, macos, pip, easy-install

I am very new to Mac. This is my first time to switch from Windows to Mac. In windows, I didn't have any problems using the commands below in a cmd:

```
pip install django
```

Now, when I tried to install it on my Mac using the same command in the terminal, I get this error13: Permission denied.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have root permission?

Comment: Your problem is that you do not have access to the directory. Since I cannot find a specific question that you have asked, that is as much as I can tell you. Please take the tour and learn how to ask questions. Thanks!

Comment: Sir Ivan, my problem is that I always get that error. All I wanted was to install django. I did it in the same way I did on Windows, but failed.

Comment: sudo pip install django, and type your password

Comment: Use a virtualenv!

Comment: @julivico , thank you. just used "sudo pip install django", and it is now working.

Comment: @NatiqVahabov thanks..too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [permission denied pip virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146065/permission-denied-pip-virtualenv)

Comment: already solved this problem. Thank to those who helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need access to the directory. You can get this using sudo (super user do).

```
sudo pip install django
```

You will have to type in your password after the command above.