# Error on terminal while installing django taggit via pip install on ubuntu gnome

Tags: python, django, web, tags, django-taggit

I am getting the error on installing django-taggit module... what might be the problem? Please help
I have tried everythin and it̀s still bringing the same error even tried updating my setup tools

```
:~$ pip install django-taggit
Collecting django-taggit
  Using cached django_taggit-0.22.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: django-taggit
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/krafty-coder/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/krafty-coder/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/krafty-coder/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/krafty-coder/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/krafty-coder/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/krafty-coder/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/krafty-coder/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/krafty-coder/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/taggit'
```

Comment: You should use `sudo pip install django-taggit`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146065/permission-denied-pip-virtualenv and others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [permission denied pip virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146065/permission-denied-pip-virtualenv)