# sudo pip install django Syntax Error

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

Basically, I set up a Virtual Box with Ubuntu Server (stable).
Installed python 3.5.1, meaning I have 2.7, 3.4.3 and now 3.5.1.
I installed virtualenv and had a lot of problems with telling it which interpreter to use, again this is due to my lack of experience. I eventually set it up using:

```
sudo virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 fmenv
```

Now, when I activate it, (after hours of changing things), if I type in:

```
python
```

I get a 3.5.1 interpreter, good.
If I do:

```
pip -V
```

I get:

```
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/.../fmenv/.../site-packages
```

also good. By the way, virtualenv is 13.1.2

The problem is that when I run:

```
sudo python -m pip install django
```

or simply just:

```
sudo pip install django
```

I get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax, (download is good, by the way).

Now I was thinking, maybe with:

```
sudo python3.5 -m pip install django
```

it can work, but it says no module named pip, so I tried to manually specify it, that didn't work also. 
Anyway, thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sudo` switches to `root` and it has no knowledge of your virtualenv.
Just run it without `sudo`. It is not needed with virtualenv.

Comment: I can't. PermissionError [Errno 13]

Comment: Run everything without sudo (create new virtualenv from scratch). That's the purpose of virtualenv, to use it as normal user and have configurable private python environment.

Comment: You doing it in `/usr` directory? Why not in your home directory, where you have full permissions access?

Comment: Nothing works, I even tried installing it outside of a venv. Same error, all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is an error you get from the python prompt not from a system shell. What's the error message you're getting when you run `pip` from the shell?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I've never used pip inside of the shell before. Tell me a command.

Comment: @AquaSolid pip install ... is command you run from a unix shell or DOS shell. These system shells is where you typed `python` earlier in order to get into the python shell. My point is that you get `SyntaxError` from the python shell not the system shells. I understand you're getting an error when you're running it from the system shell. What is it?

Comment: Considering that my venv is active with pip install django I just get a PermissionError, sudo pip install django works, but when I do pip freeze, django is not in the list. But, It's fine, since it works with sudo then it's okay, I can live with that, I can live without a venv.

Comment: @AquaSolid Cool. Although you'll have to run `sudo python` every time you want to run a Django app, which probably gets annoying with time. As ESYSCODER said, the only way to avoid this is to make sure you re-installed whatever packages are giving you permission errors without `sudo` if possible. I've been through that process before. It's annoying but better than having to run everything as `root` every time you run a django app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471972/how-to-avoid-permission-denied-when-using-pip-with-virtualenv).

Using the command:

```
sudo chown -R aquasolid:aquasolid /usr/virtu/fmenv/
```

Now it works like a charm.