# Error installing Pillow (Django)

Tags: python, django, command-line, terminal, python-imaging-library

I'm having trouble getting Pillow to install.
Here's the full traceback:

```
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-4.0.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting olefile (from Pillow)
  Using cached olefile-0.44.zip
Installing collected packages: olefile, Pillow
  Running setup.py install for olefile ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/bt/_3d4816x12d95tzvcp_0302w0000gn/T/pip-build-UyBMYN/olefile/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/bt/_3d4816x12d95tzvcp_0302w0000gn/T/pip-QHsEXV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    copying OleFileIO_PL.py -> build/lib
    creating build/lib/olefile
    copying olefile/__init__.py -> build/lib/olefile
    copying olefile/olefile.py -> build/lib/olefile
    copying olefile/README.rst -> build/lib/olefile
    copying olefile/README.html -> build/lib/olefile
    copying olefile/LICENSE.txt -> build/lib/olefile
    copying olefile/CONTRIBUTORS.txt -> build/lib/olefile
    running install_lib
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/olefile
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/olefile': Permission denied

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/bt/_3d4816x12d95tzvcp_0302w0000gn/T/pip-build-UyBMYN/olefile/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/bt/_3d4816x12d95tzvcp_0302w0000gn/T/pip-QHsEXV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/bt/_3d4816x12d95tzvcp_0302w0000gn/T/pip-build-UyBMYN/olefile/
```

The error seems to be 'Permission denied' when attempting to create the folder; though I cannot understand why...

My machine is running Mac OSX, and I'm using Terminal to run the commands for this Django project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the normal user doesn't have permission to install packages globally. Either run with `sudo`, or - much better - use a virtualenv and install your packages in there.

Answer (score 0):

There're several questions regarding this problem, I'd suggest to take a look at these:

- Using `virtualenv` https://stackoverflow.com/a/19472082/394647
- Using `$HOME`https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143496/394647

I prefer the second one but it also depends on your project/app structure