# Problems installing Pillow/PIL in virtual environment without sudo

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, python-imaging-library, permission-denied

I have a program that I can run from terminal (no virtual environment) where I install packages with the --user option. Now I want to organize the program in a proper way in Python 2.7 using requirements.txt, setup.py, etc. 
To do this I created a virtual environment and I am installing all the necessary packages, so that I can do a "pip freeze > requirements.txt".

Unfortunately I cannot install PIL/Pillow. I used to get a problem with jpeg but I fixed that with "sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev". Now with these:

```
pip install Pillow
pip install Pillow --allow-external Pillow --allow-unverified Pillow
```

I get a permission denied:

```
...
error: could not create '/home/kinkyboy/virtualenv/tantrix/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/kinkyboy/virtualenv/tantrix/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/kinkyboy/virtualenv/tantrix/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-S9cPV3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/kinkyboy/virtualenv/tantrix/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/kinkyboy/virtualenv/tantrix/build/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /home/kinkyboy/.pip/pip.log
```

If I use sudo it works and with --user it doesn't, but obviously these commands do not install in the virtual environment. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Which user constructed the virtual environment? Looks to me the virtual environment might have been constructed by the root user.

Comment: If you *ever* use `sudo` inappropriately, you can mess up permissions so you can't easily fix it. `sudo apt-get` is just about the *only* safe use.

Comment: I am reading about chown'ing the ~/.cache/pip file, but it is already owned by my user (kinkyboy), but the virtual environment is owned by root. let me try to chown the virtual environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to chown the path to the virtual environment. Make sure both ~/.cache/pip and the path to the virtual environment are both owned by the user. In my case the second was not

sudo chown -R your_username:your_username path/to/virtuaelenv/

See @Vingtoft here: 
[StackOverflow 19471972](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471972/how-to-avoid-permission-denied-when-using-pip-with-virtualenv)