# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError

Tags: python, ubuntu, keras, pip, virtualenv

I have an account on a machine with a specific envirnoment, I want to install packages such as Keras and NLTK.

```
pip install keras
```

But I have the following error:

> Installing collected packages: pyyaml, scipy, keras
>   Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/virt_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyYAML-3.13.dist-info'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I've tried --user option and not solved

> Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible
>   in this virtualenv.

I've tried

```
python3 -m pip install keras
```

Also, the same error!

I've contacted the machine admin and he told me he allowed me those permissions.
So, how to solve it?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you create the virtualenv using sudo?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471972/how-to-avoid-permission-denied-when-using-pip-with-virtualenv

Comment: ^ agreed, it is frowned upon but just to test that out try a sudo -U pip install keras --user

Comment: @JulianoSAssine yes! I didn't know if the admin created the enviroment with sudo or not. But I tried the suggestion in the link and worked! Thanks

Comment: @TheodoreHowell I've tried it but did'nt work.

Comment: @userInThisWorld I'm glad it worked. I think this should be marked as a duplicate in this case.