# I can't install garden matplotlib in my venv

Tags: python, kivy

I'm watching a video tutorial to use matplotlib in kivy, before coding he install:

```
pip install kivy_garden
```

After, he install:

```
garden install matplotlib
```

But when i try to install it in my venv, i get this error:

```
bash: /home/user/app/venv/bin/garden: Permession denied
```

If i try with sudo garden install matplotlib, i get this:

```
sudo: garden: command not found
```

I need it, because i need to use:

```
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Seems like an ownership issue. Maybe try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28984415/17200348).

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

`kivy-garden-0.1.5` is not working properly, try `0.1.4`

```
pip uninstall kivy-garden
pip install Kivy-Garden==0.1.4
garden install matplotlib --kivy
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with @Norang 's answer you should also try installing kivy_garden using sudo to avoid the permission error you're running into in your venv

```
sudo pip install Kivy-garden==0.1.4
sudo garden install matplotlib --kivy
```